# Adding values from lookup-table based on condition to data frame in R

Tags: r, reshape

I've got a data frame containing data of participants who rated images (column image_index):
[image]

Now I want to add a new column with gender specific values of the rated image from a another dataframe.
Look-up table of image data:
[image]

Final data frame:
[image]

How can I accomplish this task?

Sample data:

```
library(tidyverse)

participants_data <- data.frame(
  ID = c(1,2,3,4),
  gender = c('f','m','d','f'),
  image_index = c(19,2,2,19)
)

lookup_data <- data.frame(
  index = c(2,19),
  male = c(100,110),
  female = c(150,125),
  diverse = c(130, 90)
)


complete_dataset <- data.frame(
  ID = c(1,2,3,4),
  gender = c('f','m','d','f'),
  image_index = c(19,2,2,19),
  external_value = c(125,100,130,150)
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make a few manipulations on your data to `join` them together.

1. Pivot `lookup_data` longer with `tidyr::pivot_longer()` so the `gender` info is in a column to help merge on.
2. Use `dplyr::rename()` to make sure the column names are the same between the two tables.
3. Transform the `gender` column so it is just `1` letter to match the other table. Here I use `stringr::str_sub(x, 1,1)` which just takes the first character of a string.
4. Then I use `left_join()` to merge. Because the joining column names are already the same I don't need to specify.
5. Finally I just reorder and sort the data to match your expected output.

```r
library(tidyverse)

participants_data <- data.frame(
  ID = c(1,2,3,4),
  gender = c('f','m','d','f'),
  image_index = c(19,2,2,19)
)

lookup_data <- data.frame(
  index = c(2,19),
  male = c(100,110),
  female = c(150,125),
  diverse = c(130, 90)
)

lookup_data %>% 
  pivot_longer(-index, names_to = "gender", values_to = "external_value") %>% 
  rename(image_index = index) %>% 
  mutate(gender = str_sub(gender, 1, 1)) %>% 
  left_join(., participants_data) %>% 
  drop_na(ID) %>% 
  select(ID, gender, image_index, external_value) %>% 
  arrange(ID)
#> Joining, by = c("image_index", "gender")
#> # A tibble: 4 x 4
#>      ID gender image_index external_value
#>   <dbl> <chr>        <dbl>          <dbl>
#> 1     1 f               19            125
#> 2     2 m                2            100
#> 3     3 d                2            130
#> 4     4 f               19            125
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>